# Parabolic jump animation using javafx

Tags: animation, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm making a simple sidescrolling platformer shooter game using JavaFX. I want a very simple parabolic jump animation for the character. Currently, the character extends StackPane, and it lives on a Scene. I was told to use Interpolator.SPLINE for the jump animation, but it does not seem to be working. 
Currently, I have:

```
public void Jump(){
    TranslateTransition translation = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(1), this);
    translation.interpolatorProperty().set(Interpolator.SPLINE(.1, .1, .7, .7));
    translation.play();
}
```

but it does not seem to move at all. My other animation commands (move left and move right) are working using simple translate transition however. What am I doing wrong with the jump function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems:

- your transition doesn't move anything, you need to set where to move using your interpolator, e.g. `translation.setByY(-50);`
- `Duration.millis(1)` is 1 millisecond, you can't see anything moving so fast. Try 500

Also, if you want a jump you need to provide return movement as well. Easiest would be to revert current transition by:

```
translation.setAutoReverse(true);
translation.setCycleCount(2);
```

Example:

```
TranslateTransition translation = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(500), this);
translation.interpolatorProperty().set(Interpolator.SPLINE(.1, .1, .7, .7));
translation.setByY(-50);
translation.setAutoReverse(true);
translation.setCycleCount(2);
translation.play();
```